# Erro ao tentar instalar o NodeJs

Tags: node.js, windows-7, 32-bits

Alguem me ajuda resolver este problema?

Link do arquivo de Log criado [toque aqui para visualizar](https://github.com/kondzilla157/nodejs/raw/master/Nodejs.log)

[image: Erro ao tentar instalar o NodeJs Windows 7 32 Bits]

Comment: Está executando o instalador como administrador?

Comment: Arquivo msi, não mostra a opção para instalar como administrador. usei o Prompt de comandos em modo administrador e fiz a instalação seguindo uma ajuda na comunidade do NodeJs que serviria para criar o arquivo de Log, o arquivo esta criado. mas eu, não tenho conhecimento para identificar o problema,

Comment: Clique com o botão direito no instalador e vá em "Executar como administrador"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No momento da instalação desativa a opção `Perfomance Counters` e `Event Tracing (ETW)` e tenta instalar novamente. Em alguns casos desativar o antivirus também resolve.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Deus te abençoe mano deu tudo certo! muito obrigado mesmo